# TclOO : Export/Import Class

Tags: tcl

Is there any way to export my class, like we can do for a command with `namespace export/import` ?
My intention is to be able to use the name of my class without its namespace.

```
namespace eval ns {}
oo::class create ns::myCLass {...}

proc ns::myfunc {} {
    set c [myCLass new] ; It works
    return $c
}

# it doesn't work, outside my namespace 
set c [myCLass new]
```

Comment: As @Shawn says, you do in the same way as for a command, because a TclOO class **is** a special type of command.

Comment: TclOO objects (classes are objects) are a mix of a command and a namespace. The command really is just a regular command; any rule for a command applies to it. The namespace is just a regular namespace (albeit it is internally configured specially). *Sometimes* they have the same name, but that isn't guaranteed at all as commands can be `rename`d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`namespace export`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M12) in the namespace to mark `myCLass` as an exportable name, and then use [`namespace import`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M14) in the namespace you want to use it with an unqualified name in.

```
namespace eval ns {
    # Can be used with names that haven't been defined yet
    namespace export myCLass
}

oo::class create ns::myCLass {}

namespace import ns::myCLass
set c [myCLass new]
```

Comment: I really didn't think I could use this command to export an class, thanks.